# Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN change Flatlist state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add a selection to my FlatList and this is my code. But when I long press the item and call `setCities` I can still log the updated cities but I'm shown the error of invariant violation. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

```
const CityListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Davao City',
      temp: 23,
      description: 'Cloudy',
      isSelected: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Cebu City',
      temp: 26,
      description: 'Clear',
      isSelected: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Tokyo City',
      temp: 23,
      description: 'Snow',
      isSelected: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Singapore City',
      temp: 32,
      description: 'Sunny',
      isSelected: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Dublin City',
      temp: 18,
      description: 'Snow',
      isSelected: false,
    }
  ]);

  const renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 16,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  const onCitySelected = (city) => {
    city.isSelected = !city.isSelected;
    city.selectedClass = city.isSelected ?
      styles.itemContainerSelected : styles.itemContainer;

    const newCities = cities.map((item) => {
      return item.name === city.name ? 
        city : item;
    })

    console.log(newCities);

    setCities({ cities: newCities });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={cities}
        keyExtractor={item => item.name}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <CityItem
              city={item}
              onLongPress={(city) => onCitySelected(city)}
            />
          );
        }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatList}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

### Edit 1: (Stacktrace)

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

This error is located at:
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:632)
    in FlatList (at CityListScreen.js:84)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at CityListScreen.js:70)
    in CityListScreen (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:898)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:897)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:896)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:984)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:393)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:383)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:376)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:430)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:55)
    in Provider (at App.js:54)
    in Provider (at App.js:53)
    in Provider (at App.js:52)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at react-native-root-siblings/index.js:32)
    in RootSiblingsWrapper (at AppContainer.js:112)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:55)
    in Provider (at App.js:54)
    in Provider (at App.js:53)
    in Provider (at App.js:52)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at react-native-root-siblings/index.js:32)
    in RootSiblingsWrapper (at AppContainer.js:112)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

### Edit 2:

Result after adding `setInterval()` logs after `setCities()`

```
state Array [
  Object {
    "description": "Cloudy",
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "Davao City",
    "temp": 23,
  },
  Object {
    "description": "Clear",
    "isSelected": false,
    "name": "Cebu City",
    "temp": 26,
  },
  Object {
    "description": "Snow",
    "isSelected": false,
    "name": "Tokyo City",
    "temp": 23,
  },
  Object {
    "description": "Sunny",
    "isSelected": false,
    "name": "Singapore City",
    "temp": 32,
  },
  Object {
    "description": "Snow",
    "isSelected": false,
    "name": "Dublin City",
    "temp": 18,
  },
] object
```

Comment: Which line exactly throws this error?

Comment: @AtinSingh sorry, I added the stacktrace in the edit

Comment: No problem. It's really hard to see which line throws error from stack trace on stackoverflow since we don't have all the files and code. Can you check it on your end and tell which exact line is throwing the error?

Comment: Also what does `console.log(newCities)` logs ? I take it that it gives a non empty array right?

Comment: @AtinSingh i don't really know how to check the exact line but I think it's in the `setCities()` call, and yes the log is correct, it logs the updated list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, After re-reading your code i think i have figured out the problem try this and tell me if it works.
This usually happens when when the array passed to FlatList is not an array. Your cities state was an object.

In your onCitySelected function --

```
 const onCitySelected = (city) => {
    city.isSelected = !city.isSelected;
    city.selectedClass = city.isSelected ?
      styles.itemContainerSelected : styles.itemContainer;

    const newCities = cities.map((item) => {
      return item.name === city.name ? 
        city : item;
    })

    console.log(newCities);

   // setCities({ cities: newCities });  change this //
      setCities(newCities);
  }
```

Comment: apparently it still won't work and throws the same error :/

Comment: Hmm... strange.. can you do this below setCities call and tell me the result ? `setInterval(()=> {console.log('state', cities , typeof(cities))}, 100)` tell me what does this logs.

Comment: looks like `typeof(cities)` comes out to be an `object`. That's where the error comes. It has to be an array.

Comment: you're right, I fixed it by `setCities(newCities);` holyy, thank you so much!! You can just edit the answer, and I will accept it :D